# Purpose of using the `git-add .` command in Git

Tags: git

What is the purpose to use

```
$ git add .
```

before using

```
$ git command?
```

Is it optional or mandatory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before using `git commit` to commit your changes, you've to add file contents to the staging area, `git add` is used to add file contents to the staging area. But even if the file has already been added using `git add` command and is already been tracked, you still need to use `git add` to add any new modifications of your file to your staging area.

To recursively add all files in a project by providing the current working directory like this `git add .`. It will recursively add all files under the directory you provided.

Suppose your working directory is like this: 
    `/project`
             `|--readme.txt`
         `|--help.txt`

So if you're in project directory, and do `git add .`, it'll add readme.txt and help.txt file to staging area. It's similar to the command `git add readme.txt help.txt`. So anything which is in the staging area will be available in your next commit snapshot. Any changes that are not staged  (using git add) will not be available in your next commit snapshot.

Ref: http://gitref.org/basic/#add

Comment: Thanks. After doing it , I have to get rid of the opensdf file and ignore it (whose permission is denied). How to do so?

Comment: You can use `git rm --cached opensdf` to remove the file from the index but not the directory. Then add the file to `.gitignore`.

Comment: @NilsWerner, two encountered problems:
- it says opensdf did not match any files
- What is the command used to add that opensdf file to .gitignore?

Comment: I see! Well there was no name in it. That was why I wasn't able to see its name!

Answer (score 1):

The dot is an alias for the current directory. That command means you add everything that's inside the current directory to your git tree.

It's not mandatory, you could also add each file one at a time. This is just a handy command to set up your git tree when you're starting out.

Comment: "everything" minus what matches the contents of `.gitignore`, if one's there

Comment: The same can be achieved while `commit`ing by passing the `-a` flag as follows **`git commit -a`** thereby eliminating the need to do a `git add .`

Comment: @hus787 how to include one file in .gitignore?

Comment: @MelMed you mean how to include a specific file in `.gitignore` that you want `git` to ignore? if so, then say the `.gitignore` file is kept in root(where `.git` resides) and you want `git` to ignore `foo.bar` and `bar\bar.foo` then specifically add there names(the way I have mentioned) relative to the location of `.git`, each on a separate line. Take [this](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/.gitignore) e.g., here they are specifically asking `git` to ignore `r2/r2/public/static/names.json`. [For more](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html)

Answer (score 0):

While using '.' to select all files for inclusion in your next commit, don't forget to set up your .gitignore file which is used to list all those files and file types that you would like git to ignore and NOT include in your next commit.

It can be difficult removing old build artefacts that have been accidentally commited once they are fully pushed into history (It's manageable if it is just the last commit and it is still only in your local repo, wher you can just ammend the commit).

If a file has already been added by using '.', then the update of .gitignore doesn't stop that [existing] file being tracked - in that case you need to actively use 'git rm' to remove the unwanted ignorable file from git.